# How to insert subdocument into array field only if there's no document with the same "key": "value" pair (MongoDB)?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents that look like this:

```
{
  "AAA": 1,
  "BBB": [
    {
      "CCC": 1,
      "DDD": [1,2,3]
    }
  ]
}
```

How to insert a new subdocument (`{"CCC": 1, "DDD": []}`) into "BBB" array only if there's no object with {"CCC": 1} key pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this in a couple of ways, the easiest would be to make the query 'fail' to match if the document has `CCC: 1`, like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {
        _id: docId,
        'BBB.CCC': {
            $ne: 1,
        },
    },
    {
        '$push': {
            BBB: {
                'CCC': 1,
                'DDD': [],
            },
        },
    },
);
```

Now if the document has a `BBB.CCC` value of 1 then the update will not find a document to update and nothing will be updated as you expect.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4hwbDTolVkY)